# "Hello, World!" in zero lines of code

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, hello-world

NPM's [sloc](https://github.com/flosse/sloc) is a moderately popular tool for counting source lines of code in a file. The tool will attempt to strip out both single and multiline comments and count the remaining lines in order to get an estimate of the 'true' number of lines of code.

However, the parser used is based on regular expressions and is quite simple, so it can be tricked. In this challenge, you will need to construct a hello world program that `sloc` counts as *zero lines of code*.

### The challenge

1. Download `sloc`. If you have npm, this can be done via `npm i sloc`. We will use the latest version as of the time of posting, which is `0.2.1`. Or, use the online testing environment linked at the bottom of this post.
2. Select any language that `sloc` supports. A full list is available [here](https://github.com/flosse/sloc#supported-languages).
3. Write a **full program** in that language that prints the exact string `Hello, World!` to stdout. The output may optionally have a trailing newline, but no other format is accepted. The program may output anything to stderr. However, to be considered a valid submission, `sloc` must see the program as zero lines of source code. You can verify this by running `sloc myprogram.ext`, which should read `Source :  0`.

### Example

The following Python program is a valid submission:

```python
'''"""''';print("Hello, World!");"""'''"""
```

If I run `sloc hello.py`, I get:

```
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  1
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

Why? Well, [sloc uses `'''` or `"""` to determine if something is a mulitline comment](https://github.com/flosse/sloc/blob/6f74142bdc90e4d3a5cab98e14f42460fcd4c072/src/sloc.coffee#L89) in Python. However, it doesn't pair them up correctly. Thus Python parses our program as:

```
'''"""''';print("Hello, World!");"""'''"""
\-------/ \--------------------/ \-------/
 comment        active code       comment
```

But `sloc` parses it as:

```
'''"""''';print("Hello, World!");"""'''"""
\----/\----------------------------/\----/
comment          comment           comment
```

(This is not the shortest valid Python submission, so it shouldn't stop you looking for shorter ones)

### Scoring

The shortest program in bytes wins.

### A note on feasibility

It might be a reasonable question to ask whether this is possible for all languages. I don't know, but all the ones I've looked at so far (Python, C, HTML) have at least one solution. So there's a very good chance it is possible in your language.

There are a number of ideas that can work across multiple languages.

### Online test environment

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVltj9u4Ef6uX8G1e7CdteXdHA7IJXG217tre@ilAZoA/bD2HWSJtrSrtxPpXRub/PZ03ihTshO0H7oLiDQ1MxwOh88MR3G12Wht4iar7fPPw@Ew@JBmRtVNtW2iQkE3yYxtsvXO6kTtykQ3yqZaWd0URlUb@vH2lw8qz2JdGh0GP1b1ocm2qVXPr66fqxk2L9Q4nqi3UXO/M@ofVZqnkdHqdRFl@Z8LGp3dy2iY6DcB6hHc64NRC3UbKDWylY3ykaK/oarTg8niKIdJS01axFWikc5UuybWI6FrX/MwEsRVUejSjnyCx8ymSl4YkpKV27wnhYj4xQxHOgzrvIrvW/U8BnrRIS2yvU56pDSmdrVMQsqqqExO5/i5qO1hBIwaO/5MUXcu5NBMLFN5HGzRpBpBZxUEZVWSXKRbqPntb0uzmge6TN5tfsWV0uif5kVQ6sdfaUYeWpbzbUBiZRTGgPcZkG4DlO@IcTx89uHdT@9Cfhlstf2RFf15XzfamKwqcbPHeVRuJ2r2JghQZ7a36ttbhhcBKmJg@XGqkDEIeLGPqS7VICbXHkzVAFwzGcg7BXoPYYlPqzlMAB6X2mirysqqTZXn1SNsxPqgqlqXMImKd01@UOsmIu/xZDcotz7gMzf4LKo4zbBTZntsiKBZ4/MuJ2J6HqKC2pTfgwRfr3lnkjsSfGdIXsG/Ynrws66p4fE9UaVESg98Llvh8DdImSFlSmbIyoomiR4iUjKtpfkO2y293DZV9XA4EWdiQ1PnmtuGnibiX8YeaKEGzimJhn3aWOxYcyLqLkpoo7bEWu6I7l6ehplI3Y3hZ8YNja1NfiIwiRrijrZJ5Ft4/vT807zrJnlkNcmRBhQng8K2tozGgjxy@W@6W5TvaG0pL/mP3JtrNuuS6sZ/2xe0bsSLSoA97D2sPepRl7jMiuPLRs6BkM7n3q/xzUvPKkNw83IWR7XdNejcsK@72jeb@q1DzasG@MTz16GD8zNcPXN0UXlQcRo1CoKEGg1HHunEV8aX0Io/VWI59Kn0PopBCQCAr0j@H5c5vrnwqfU2stkDwExV3UepjpIOMax2OVxerM6vlWB6dDHqsEy@oKe/OU34exEBcP0NtfsdfOsapCdZAzC8yfZHss7GN3wm4vxOGnKalBwmMp5TzF/1/JRIsvxwxqd7nrj5/ooO1/eEAJurb7l5Qc31C9@HLxynziGcl7s8J9genoa9E5D@GkQ7zYytajp0w6dv3an9PyDjf4OLjPEC7V2Q9CUxXgoutkh4Hif7@NiHRQHDFny/BouIPNPzqHeErvny2eW8HQXT0ugzwMTrrnXrg02r8hjgvCh1sjUD2JqPy1F/g1I4FrleR7zWdM3gtgP2ONWnqj3B/0VHNxz9tOwJNWc4ZydLmvXZrIRcS9tvHrbY7HnwYXeqzuvlxeyM2NmbjliE/j7nbLa8pQhzwrtcHSMP8wvU90UMG13Ms76AIWRjMBqcjQEAYVmBqQwAn2o05MXd80dYlVTxccBU6lFTZg8AuctM2kpaa/uoQf65zIuwzpdzshtDb/FD1h5uEKB7J4oIlq1Pd3Ox1tusPHXSBS7fXz0C4Ynllh9POT8Ou8CRn046XC7OzLjsMrK3FHl2Ngs5kTlePjt31CZdD@qD8hGSl08n7N@0bo1oK2@zDWGqykoIlBYuYJRHWxTfO6qEzh5a27SpHiH2PaoPh1r/3DRVowZ/zWDPW0EQ355Q@qcR7iKmyGZX11VjEapB1hPPMaUpps5lPgVBXO1K@5YuNZDSQ3o/5XvHVGXJfspcv2CPIqBL92EtY3cVCfVex8x0e7WakOehoDCPjL0JnWeBOAV6O4EyxCEXqeliFdY7kzLNS6dAVVOXZyUtbmiOc/PPrsNwBVqEZreGq7C6Er3DDG7D@6/MdVwnT@h@0/XnPQz9S2/1Hk1kYQumIAV@kjXagIkvjh7TXkxpg9sLmkfgLqJEQPLQPkdKnBn3GydlYbIdMi1Yg72O91JsYsWZRK5TIxBXAib3vqUXfutpFXie61jYhur1Qjjkt8/Gc7RzBmR73GxYQoFqq0K4LlWB25TrcmvTQG6mfK2MiTAOiXl8vLNOboQczXQV0A235Ctrj8fdffscdM8tzRmO9gbcZyFt320o86NVIPlUlW4PcGldD8v2lzJ0m7kFwn21URme/Ftw0HJFZGKen/QGJk7aGcATplQjkSnAX2EYRm/Y0aV8MlRU/KGiDyaiGDcyqx6r5t6oV7MJOwgw82EZb50QP5Wd3LRHgrdloToLJjjYOhrYMBJibrcrVkzg40cXdNCuoJ5/PICwOBidb1p4YQo8@7xAlATpf0krzbg@hOsajZz74QhOjoPLcuRODDGhT7H8VnhosMA1vp5M1eUlIkdwBGy3XR2rk7ahAKTY91i5@DKDHEriIJZdiYmju4w1IkKg3ENaT9U6z@wYVzWZCsp1LcKCLeOAQ4QOHDAFKYkhpAdGZ@Goo9cZNPLkxu8dYIshsEsdfs1bT6eQF0TAS/UYx0mEuStGnRCOuyA9YZvQTh83DmcFTpLiDtUM7mGXrdE4@PIEpzs27sC4h@EUnybTthbX3ceqbjfEhJoC70IdtPnCNmkpzS1UC2g9o3gLnXq2vTzatp3UmXbhep6YK45TXlgDm8jiBRePxUWwDVr0BxLlTenEijkvSaSHyqxEos9tmhMpTtJz7a9kEEGLOJgeUM7z1QAMaoE6UzboS25aQMJ9XHEcdxJZ/hlUmPZEIqFtoqKuKHEW8ic@Gi9vV1POzKlH@QL0PjlRGEyOvIBsJWRigmfYpW3Y2/EEThfmaagopNX0ClFssytjC2nbSOiDAAW93xUMoQynLr2g0SvoYRSJpxRHOmk9pW4xZ1ozFYeSJVyqa349mzGKMsttdnm9umEiVIYZ2U9gKoheCc8aBAYs8LZKdgSDAu2YZU5VVdvF0yeH8HJeZJUOwAfsKpwxn81hR0g6ouuQreA@oyLleALxPXG8Rtd5FGvIzJtl@XHZzEEHQQiP7PYqDMPZ9aoNGpQPurhBO44fJzhnQPBozwqGW9AIDfaFQyyh2B0GP@yxYc7XyamMckzSGMJwo9FhWxzmS2D/NY1iAKWT1X9Lo4GPEyzl8gjvmNawwi71kZWsCU/JDGv2G/StNXpWO/HkKBscCN8b915WQ5HDOE8qSapbDH@lYL/1BsC79iFbGCXuOzOinfiDCmmMOzVrlzeTjbnsiGPbsLeUpoKsNK@2LpMAJw0Tvd5t@QsFjO5yS5chEj6V2Vrwn7aBlaaQcy/YMyUbTv3Z4frk3eT481db0HFFPioXYxvzU5r8zrXyNpeWy2zUrWtuG26EwEi7p7ssF5KwI0VrKgpy@x23V99K@4Lba2nP3IyxKkYNV7ICLm1hk/LzpFYUSFGOWlY0lVGvlkO/99JIy@JdMdHdramaF7jvDNx5YINyQWAgBrsTjQv5zVUGKrZhy58KqKfFYjKBFIMGYvAilybjlr4Ncc8VfTrVMKoscsvrwloftn6pkX6zYC7IDdg0XEhxJRFXrRuIh1AVkjpUaAzchxvq2INrWS7Wxqj9Q37TNxvsuYWLJawYir9SuCoaFdWwpa9ctEh@itMaGFz5ESDsuPrxR4dGvgNjEwRD9cPbn1wdIoDzmFBGdhNGRXLDiSaPYLg@CkHGfyLm35mW2d1dC6LAmxAOG5FSOAVpEHOKjrC/QOQxujkR9gjZU/UoMvhHiJw9AcYmAFIL/M4egyuF@L3xPY6NJ4HEnsGAqUIsxCSRjUZTCJfprrznWyZSAfLRiEcJd30gpCDvo5cXdTmyuJmjZvtw@3z1@fPn0Wg0GAzg@aqGcGnHg7/rPAdw@nfV5MnFYPKK38Lzc334Dw)

You need to:

1. Type your code into the input box
2. Type the extension corresponding to your language into the command args (important!)

Comment: [This file might be of some help](https://github.com/flosse/sloc/blob/master/src/sloc.coffee)

Comment: *sloc* recognizes [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/19f/1HDioKizLwSDSWP1JycfB2F8PyinBQlzf//AQ) correctly as two lines, I give up :/

Comment: I will point out that our definition of what counts as a programming language is entirely vestigial, and challenges are not restricted to only "programming languages".  They used to be but [not anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/56656).  You are of course free to override the defaults.  I just don't see a good reason why you are in this case, and thought maybe you didn't know about the new consensus (you wouldn't be the first).

Comment: Is there a way to run sloc online, rather than needing to install it locally?

Comment: @WheatWizard I was not aware of the new consensus. Is there some way the [old consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/48931) can be marked with a warning?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Despite not knowing coffeescript I've managed to stumble my way into creating a TIO-based online checker. It's now in the last section of the post.

Comment: Given that the empty program in Stuck outputs Hello, World, it’s a good thing it isn’t on `sloc`

Comment: @Sisyphus I had already left a comment and attempted to close it as a duplicate, which would leave a link to the new version, however neither of these has worked.

Comment: I had no luck with Lisp (Racket). :(

Comment: @DarkSuniuM It can be done in Racket! [Hint.](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-30.html)

Comment: Sooo, who's going to [open an issue](https://github.com/flosse/sloc/issues) and link this post there?

Comment: Hypothetical programming language that outputs "Hello world" on empty input: 0 sloc

Answer (score 43):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>[36](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/215715/1)</s> 35 bytes

```haskell
{-{--}--}main=putStr"Hello, world!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1q3Wle3VheIcxMz82wLSkuCS4qUPIBy@ToK5flFOSmKSv//AwA)

[Test sloc](https://tio.run/##tVltc9s2Ev7OXwFL15EUi5SdTmfStKqvTXt3nWsuM5d8s9QORUIibb6VIG1pHP/23L6BAiklc/fhnAwBgbuLxWLx7GIZldut1iaq06p5@Wk8HnsfktSoqi53dZgr6Mapaep00zY6Vm0R61o1iVaNrnOjyi39ePvrB5WlkS6MDrw3ZXWo013SqJdX1y@Vj80rNY1m6m1Y37dG/bNMsiQ0Wn2fh2n215xG/XsZDWL9g4d6ePf6YNRS3XpKTZqyCbOJor@xqpKDSaMwg0kLTVpEZayRzpRtHemJ0HWveRgJojLPddFMXILHtEmUvDAkJS122UAKEfELH0d6DJusjO479RwGetEjzdO9jgekNKbaSiYhZVVYxKdz/JJXzWECjBo77kxhfy7k0EwsUzkcbNG4nEBn7XlFWZBcpFuqxe3vK7NeeLqI321/w5XS6F8WuVfox99oRh5aFYudR2JlFMaA9wWQ7jyUb4lxPHjx4d3P7wJ@6e1084YV/WVf1dqYtCxws6dZWOxmyv/B81Bntrca2luGlx4qYmD5UaKQ0fN4sY@JLtQoItcezdUIXDMeyTsFeo9hiU/rBUwAHpc04U4VZaO2ZZaVj7ARm4MqK13AJCpq6@ygNnVI3uPIrlFudcBnZvCZl1GSYqdI99gQQb3B511GxPQ8hDm1Cb8HCa5ei94kdyT4zpC8nH9F9OBnVVHD43uiSoiUHvhcdcLhb5QwQ8KUzJAWJU0SPoSkZFJJ8w22O3q5q8vy4XAizkSGps40tzU9Tci/THOghRo4pyQa9mnbYKcxJ6Luwpg2akesRUt09/I0zETqbg0/U25obGOyE4FxWBN3uItD18KLp5fPi76bZGGjSY40oDgZFLa1YzQNyCOX/6q/RVlLa0t4yX9mzly@3yfVtft2KGhTixcVAHvYe9g41JM@cZHmx5e1nAMhXSycX9Ob145VxuDmhR@FVdPW6Nywr23lmk393qPmVQN84vnr0cH5Ga9fWLqwOKgoCWsFQUJNxhOHdOYq40roxJ8qsRq7VHofRqAEAMAXJP@Py5zeXLjUehc26QPATFneh4kO4x4xrHY1Xl2sz6@VYHpyMemxzD6jp7s5dfBHHgJw/R21@wN86xqkx2kNMLxN90ey3sbXfCai7E4acpqEHCY0jlMsvhv4KZGk2eGMTw88cfvtFR2ubwkBtldfc/OKmutXrg9fWE6dQTgv2iwj2B6fhr0TkP4SRFvNTFNWdOjGT1/bU/t/QMb/BhcZ4wXa@yDpSmK8FFzskPA8Tg7xcQiLAoYd@H4JFhF55udR7whdi9WLy0U3Cqal0ReAidd961aHJimLY4BzotTJ1oxgaz6uJsMNSuBYZHoT8lqTDYNbC@xRok9Ve4J/Fz3dcPR5NRBqznD6J0vyh2yNhNyGtt887LDZ8@BDe6rO96sL/4xY/4eeWIT@Iafvr24pwpzwrtbHyMP8AvVDEeNa54t0KGAM2RiMemdjAEBYmmMqA8Cnag15cf/8EVbFZXQcMKV61JTZA0C2qUk6SRvdPGqQfy7zIqxz5ZzsxthZ/Ji1hxsE6N6LIoJlm9PdXG70Li1OnXSJy3dXj0B4YrnVx1POj@M@cGSnk45XyzMzrvqM7C15lp7NQk5kTlcvzh21Wd@DhqB8hOTV0wn7V51bI9rK23RLmKrSAgJlAxcwyqMbFD84qoTODlo3SV0@Qux7VB8Olf6lrstajf6Wwp53giC@PaH05wnuIqbIpq2qsm4QqkHWE88xpynm1mWePS8q26J5S5caSOkhvZ/zvWOu0ng/Z65fsUcR0Kb7sJapvYoEeq8jZrq9Ws/I81BQkIWmuQmsZ4E4BXpbgTLEIRep6WIVVK1JmOa1VaCsqMuzkhY3NMe5@f3rIFiDFoFpN3AVVleid5DCbXj/hbmO6@QJ7W@6/ryHoX/rnd6jiRrYgjlIgZ9kjS5g4oujx3QXU9rg7oLmENiLKBGQPLTPkRJnxv3GSVmYbIdMC9Zgr@O9FJs04kwi16rhiSsBk33f0Qt/42jlOZ5rWdiG6vulcMhvl43n6Ob0yPa42bCEHNVWuXBdqhy3KdPFrkk8uZnytTIiwigg5unxzjq7EXI005VHN9yCr6wDHnv3HXLQPbcwZzi6G/CQhbR9t6XMj1aB5HNV2D3ApfU9LN1fytBtahcI99VapXjyb8FBizWRiXl@1luYOO5mAE@YU41EpgB/hWEYvWFHl/LJWFHxh4o@mIhi3Egb9VjW90Z958/YQYCZD8t0Z4W4qezspjsSvC1L1VswwcHO0sCGkRBzu1uzYgIfb2zQQbuCeu7xAML8YHS27eCFKfDs8wJREqT/Ba005foQrmsyse6HIzg5Dq6KiT0xxIQ@xfI74YHBAtf0ejZXl5eIHN4RsO129axO2gYCkGLfY@Xi8wxyKImDWNoCE0d7GatFhEC5g7SOqlWWNlNc1WwuKNe3CAtuGAcsIvTggClISQwhAzA6C0c9vc6gkSM3em8BWwyBXerwa956OoW8IAJeqsdYTiLMbDHqhHDaB@kZ24R2@rhxOCtwkhR7qHy4h112RuPgyxOc7ti0B@MOhlN8ms27Wlx/H8uq2xATaAq8S3XQ5jPbpKU0t1QdoA2M4ix07tj28mjbblJr2qXtOWKuOE45YQ1sIosXXDwWF8E2aNEfSZQzpRUr5rwkkQ4qsxKxPrdpVqQ4ycC1v5BBeB3iYHpAOc8XAzCoBerM2aCvuekACfdxzXHcSmT5Z1BhPhCJhE0d5lVJibOQP/HReH27nnNmTj3KF6D3bEVhMDnyArIVkIkJnmGXtmHfTGdwujBPQ0UhraZXiGLbtogaSNsmQu95KOh9mzOEMpza9IJGr6CHUSSaUxzppfWUukWcafkqCiRLuFTX/Nr3GUWZ5Ta9vF7fMBEqw4zsJzAVRK@YZ/U8AxZ4W8YtwaBAO2aZc1VWzfLp2SK8nBdZpQXwEbsKZ8xnc9gJkk7oOtSUcJ9RobI8nvieOF6tqyyMNGTm9ar4uKoXoIMghEN2exUEgX@97oIG5YM2btCO48cJzhkQPLqzguEWNEKDfeYQSyi2h8ENe2yY83VyKqMckzSGMNxodNgOh/kSOHxNoxhA6WQN39Ko5@IES7k8wjumNaywTX1kJRvCUzLDhv0GfWuDntVNPDvKBgfC98a@l9VQ5DDWkwqSahfDXynYb50B8K59wBZGifvejGgn/qBCGuNO@d3yfNmYy544tg17S2FKyEqzcmczCXDSINabdsdfKGC0zRq6DJHwuczWgf@8C6w0hZx7wZ452XDuzg7XJ@cmx5@/uoKOLfJRuRjbiJ/SZHe2lbeZtFxmo25VcVtzIwRG2j3dZbmQhB0pWlNRkNtvuL36WtpX3F5Le@ZmjFUxariS5XFpC5uEnye1Ik@KctSyoomMOrUc@r2XRloWb4uJ9m5N1TzPfmfgzgMblAsCIzHYnWicy2@uMlCxDVv@VEA9LRaTCaQYNBKD55k0Kbf0bYh7tujTq4ZRZZFbXhfW@rB1S430mwVzQW7EpuFCii2J2GrdSDyEqpDUoUKjZz/cUKc52JblYm2M2j/lN32zwZ5duFiiEUPxVwpbRaOiGrb0lYsWyU9xWgODazcCBD1XP/7o0ch3YGw8b6x@fPuzrUN4cB5jyshugjCPbzjR5BEM10chyPgvxPw70zHbu2tOFHgTwmEjUnKrIA1iTtET9hNEHqPrE2GPkD2VjyKDfwTIORBgmhhAaonf2SNwpQC/N77HsenMk9gzGjFVgIWYOGzCyRzCZdIW93zLRCpAPhpxKOGuD4QU5F30cqIuRxY7c1jvHm5frj99@vTkP/n@M/zPw7RYVi3ktvXoHzrLAKDgCpjFF6NPifkP)

Since sloc is regex based it is a very good guess to think it cannot identify nested comments.  And if we take a look we see that indeed it cannot.  If we nest two comments as so:

```
{-{--}-}
```

sloc identifies one line of source and one line of comment.  Based on these observations my best guess is that the regex it is using is

```regex
(\{-((?!-\}).)*-\}|--[^\n]*)
```

If we pop this into a regex engine we will see it matches the nested comment as so:

```
      code
      ^^
{-{--}-}
^^^^^^
comment
```

Ok so we broke it, however this has the opposite of the intended effect.  We want sloc to think our code is a comment rather than our comment is code.  So we add a "line comment marker" to the part of the comment sloc thinks is code, so that sloc thinks a line comment is being started.

```
{-{--}--}
```

So to sloc there are two comments the block comment `{-{--}` and the line comment `--}` but to haskell which actually parses comments, it is all one block comment.

So then we just add our code after.  Sloc thinks this is still a comment and Haskell knows it is not.

Comment: You only need two `-` between the`}`s.

Comment: Interestingly, my tool of choice `cloc` is also fooled by your code, unlike most of the other answers!

Answer (score 33):

## Java 6, <s>83</s> <s>68</s> 54 Bytes

The code :

```
/**/enum C{C;{System.out.print("Hello, World!");}}/**/
```

Although crashes immediately with error sent to stderr, prints the correct output. Thanks to `@Kevin Cruijssen` for the tip about removing the `System.exit(0)`.

And the result :

```
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  1
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

Thanks @Razetime for the hint from @OlivierGrégoire [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/140175#140175).

---

My initial answer was in java 7+ with 83 Bytes (there's a comma missing) :

```
/**/interface C{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("Hello World!");}}/**/
```

Comment: [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140175/80214) may be of some help.

Comment: @Razetime Thanks. I do not have comment upvote privileges yet.

Comment: Very nice! This appears to be a generic approach that covers any language with `/*` and `*/` multi line comments.

Comment: An alternate solution for the same length is to prefix your code with `//\u000a`.

Comment: In the third rule it states "_The program may output anything to stderr._", so you can removed the `System.exit(0);` in your Java 6 answer. It will first output the "Hello, World!", and then print an exception to STDERR. PS: You forgot the comma in the string "Hello, World!" in both of your programs.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I actually noticed the missing comma yesterday, something came up and I forgot to edit it, thanks for reminding me. The stderr thing is a good point too.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire is it better now?

Answer (score 33):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```groovy
/**/print"Hello, World!"/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P9fX0tLv6AoM69EySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVEJJP7/PwA)

---

## [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```
/**/print("Hello, World!")/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4szSwqSs35/19fS0u/oCgzr0RDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJEyTz/z8A)

---

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 30 bytes

```swift
/**/print("Hello, World!")/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f9fX0tLv6AoM69EQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSRMk8/8/AA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
/**/console.log("Hello, World!")/**/
```

<s>As a bonus, this also breaks SE's syntax highlighter.</s> (seems to be fixed)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fX0tLPzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSRMk//8/AA)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
/**/main(){puts("Hello, World!");}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fS0s/NzEzT0OzuqC0pFhDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ07oWpOL/fwA)

---

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 39 bytes

```dart
/**/main(){print("Hello, World!");}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/X19LSz83MTNPQ7O6oCgzr0RDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ07oWpOT/fwA)

---

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```rust
/**/fn main(){print!("Hello, World!")}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/X19LSz8tTyE3MTNPQ7O6oCgzr0RRQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSbMWpOr/fwA)

---

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```cpp
/**/main(){__builtin_puts("Hello, World!");}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/X19LSz83MTNPQ7M6Pj6pNDOnJDMvvqC0pFhDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ07oWpPb/fwA)

---

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```scala
/**/object H extends App{print("Hello, World!")}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/19fS0s/PykrNblEwUMhtaIkNS@lWMGxoKC6oCgzr0RDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJsxak/v9/AA)

---

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 69 bytes

```go
/**/package main
import."fmt"
func main(){Print("Hello, World!")}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8///19fS0u/IDE5OzE9VSE3MTOPKzO3IL@oRE8pLbdEiSutNC8ZLKyhWR1QlJlXoqHkkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqKRZCzLg/38A)

---

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 75 bytes

```cs
/**/class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("Hello, World!");}}/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/X19LSz85J7G4WCGgurgksSQzWaEsPzNFwTcxM09Dszq4srgkNVfPOT@vOD8nVS@8KLMkVUPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUnTurYWZMz//wA)

Comment: With .NET 5 C# you can omit the class declaration and the main method and just write `System.Console.Write("Hello world!");` (46 bytes) as a valid code. Sadly, it does not seem to be an option available in `tio.run` yet... :)

Comment: It's funny that the JS code _also_ tricks SE's syntax highlighter.

Comment: Can the C version end with `//` rather than `/**/`?

Comment: Apparently the app uses a different syntax highlighter that handles it correctly.

Comment: @wastl the first time the app has ever had something work better!

Comment: @mishan The same is true of C# Interactive, which tio does provide

Comment: Fix for syntax highlighter for [JavaScript](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2897) and [Dart](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2899).

Comment: For the Go entry, you can avoid importing "fmt" by using Go's built-in println function, although it's not guaranteed to remain in the language ;) https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println

Comment: @Velovix, The challenge asks you to `Write a full program in that language that prints the exact string Hello, World! to stdout.`; since the builtin prints to stderr I don't think it is valid

Comment: @Mukundan314 Good catch. I didn't know it went to stderr.

Answer (score 30):

## PHP, 33 bytes

[Dewi Morgan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41364/dewi-morgan) [claimed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215732/26597) there was no possible solution, so that obviously made me look further into a way to do it :) (he then [followed up](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215752/26597) with multiple 'shenanigans')

Thing is, we can simply do:

```php
//<?php ob_clean()?>Hello, World!
```

The only downside (and what made me initially discard it) is that you must be using a SAPI that has buffering enabled by default. So, if you tried to run it with php cli, it will probably output the `//` *and* complain that there was no buffer to delete. But if ran from a web server (even built-in `php -S`), it will produce the expected `Hello World!`

sloc agrees that has no code:

```
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  1
       Block comment :  0
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

Comment: This is really, really clever. I like it!

Comment: Woops, fixed @KevinCruijssen

Comment: That's fire! Well done.

Comment: If you allow for differing PHP configuration you can make sure short_open_tags is enabled (isn't that even default?) and then replace `<?php  ` with `<?`, thus 4 bytes less

Comment: Oh and PHP also supports `#` for single line comments. If sloc supports it: one more byte less.

Comment: For PHP, I was expecting the answer would involve calling system level commands to change sloc on the fly so it prints the results needed.

Answer (score 24):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 28 bytes

```javascript
/**/print`Hello, World!`/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/X19LS7@gKDOvJMEjNScnX0chPL8oJ0UxAST@/z8A)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer.

Comment: You should edit your answer to also say "TypeScript" as it also works in TypeScript[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6ksSC1OLsosKPn/X19LS7@gKDOvJMEjNScnX0chPL8oJ0UxAST@/z8A), and in the "Online test environment" set the extension to ts.

Answer (score 21):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 17 chars *with backspace cheat*.

### Entry

```
//^H^HHello, World!
```

### Rationale

After the forward-slashes for the comment, there are two backspace characters which erase them from the output. Then, it outputs the target string.

So, whether this is legal depends on whether "output" can be grossly misinterpreted to mean "eventual visual output on some terminals". I suspect not, since the online testing env is probably the canonical env, and does not respect backspaces. So while maybe mildly interesting for the weaknesses found, this is unlikely to be a winner :)

However, that then means that **a legal solution is impossible in PHP.**

For any solution which does not include this cheat, we are stuck with two options:

1. Comments, then PHP opentag. This outputs `//`, and we've established that's illegal:

   ```
   //<?php
   ```
2. PHP open tag, then comments. Lacking any preceding text to hide it from sloc, the open tag counts as a line of code.

   ```
   <?php//
   ```

This argument relies on the assumption that comments are the *only* way to hide code from sloc.

However, the argument works just as well if we replace "comments" with "anything which causes bad output if placed before a PHP opentag; and won't hide the opentag from sloc if placed after it", which I *think* includes everything, since the regexes for PHP don't seem to have any exploitable backreferencing, but I may be making an incorrect assumption.

### Weaknesses found

Possibly-exploitable issues found with the sloc online testing env for PHP.

1. It treats `//` line and `/*...*/` comments correctly, but is sadly unaware of `#` line comments, or this would be 15 chars instead, standing a good chance of beating all languages other than those using compression or with the "Hello World!" string as a language construct. OK, or languages where `//` means `print` and the file extension can be set to .c or similar.
2. It does not check for a preceding unpaired `<?` or `<?php` before considering something code. To PHP, everything outside of `<?....?>` is output. This is the bug I exploited.

Comment: To get a legal PHP solution, one could consider using the `-r` flag

Comment: @Sisyphus you're right, I misremembered! Commandline params to the compiler ARE permitted by standard loopholes! :) They just count towards the total, which is fine.

Comment: They don't actually count towards the total

Comment: @JoKing You're joking, right? :D Well, I'm a noob, so may be misunderstanding. But, if that's the case, just about every compiler allows code to be passed in as parameters, so every code golf contest could be 0 characters for every language, and it would be quite boring indeed. So, most likely, I'm misunderstanding. Do you mean that, in `php -r 'echo "hi";'`, the leading `php -r '` and the trailing `'` are not counted?

Comment: My understanding is that at the very least *nonstandard* parameters are counted, but I see no definition for "nonstandard". I'd consider -r nonstandard though: of all PHP processes running in the world, I'd doubt even 0.1% are -r processes.

Comment: It's a bit confusing,, but [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/76162) is the current meta consensus on flags. According to this, yes only the part inside the string parameter would be counted, though it would technically be the language PHP with the `-r` flag. Zero byte abuses of this would fall under the [MetaGolfScript loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/76162)

Comment: @JoKing Thank you! :D If I understand right, that means I can make a separate answer for the "language" (well, maybe dialect might be a better term), called "PHP -r". This makes a -r solution possible! Though, the quotes feel like they SHOULD be counted... if only to make the answer more challenging :D

Answer (score 13):

## HTML, <s>[25](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/215733/1)</s> 23 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [anonymoose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215705/hello-world-in-zero-lines-of-code/215733#comment503997_215733)

```html
<!-->Hello, World!<!-->
```

---

A side note on PHP:

Inspired by @Dewi Morgan's PHP answer, I wanted to see if I could find any other approaches which did not use the backspace cheat.

My first thought was that my HTML answer would instantly work as a PHP answer, however this is not the case. Even though PHP interprets everything outside of its `<?` `?>` tags as plain HTML, simply switching the extension from HTML to PHP causes sloc to interpret this as one line, and indeed it seems that sloc ignores HTML comments in PHP mode.

I was hoping that something like `//?>Hello, World!` would solve this for PHP, but while sloc interprets this as 0 lines (hooray!!) PHP simply ignores the closing tag meaning that the entire construct is output to the page.

So, for now I have to agree: it seems like a valid PHP solution without the backspace cheat (or using the `-r` flag) does not exist.

Comment: It seems that browsers also accept `<!-->Hello, World!<!-->` (23 characters), and sloc still counts it as a comment. From looking through the other solutions, this may be the shortest solution without "cheats."

Comment: @anonymoose Thanks!

Comment: This is also valid PHP!

Comment: @johannes It is, but sloc sees it as a line when set to PHP mode sadly :(

Answer (score 10):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
"""'''""";print("Hello, World!")
```

`sloc` outputs

```
{ total: 1,
  source: 0,
  comment: 1,
  single: 0,
  block: 1,
  mixed: 0,
  empty: 0,
  todo: 0,
  blockEmpty: 0 }
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X0lJSV1dHUhaFxRl5pVoKHmk5uTk6yiE5xflpCgqaf7/DwA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
=begin
=end =begin
puts "Hello, World!"
#=end
```

[sloc output](https://tio.run/##tVltb9vIEf7OX7GWepBkS5Sd4IBcLjr3mqTtoZcGaAL0g6U7UORKpM2345K2BMe/PZ23pZaUYrQfagPc1XJmdnZ29pnZYVhsNlqbsErK@sXX4XDofY4To8qq2FZBpqAbJaauknVT60g1eaQrVcda1brKjCo29OPDL59VmoQ6N9r33hblvkq2ca1eXF69UDNsXqlxOFEfguquMeofRZzGgdHqTRYk6Z8zGp3dyagf6Z881MO703ujFurGU2pUF3WQjhT9DVUZ700SBilMmmvSIiwijXSmaKpQj4Sufc3DSBAWWabzeuQSPCR1rOSFISlJvk17UoiIX8xwpMOwTovwrlXPYaAXHdIs2emoR0pjqillElJWBXl0PMf7rKz3I2DU2HFnCrpzIYdmYpnK4WCLRsUIOivPy4uc5CLdQs1vflua1dzTefRx8yuulEb/NM@8XD/8SjPy0DKfbz0SK6MwBrznQLr1UL4lxnH//PPHdx99fultdf2WFX2/KyttTFLkuNnjNMi3EzX7yfNQZ7a36ttbhhceKmJg@WGskNHzeLEPsc7VICTXHkzVAFwzGsg7BXoPYYmPqzlMAB4X18FW5UWtNkWaFg@wEeu9KkqdwyQqbKp0r9ZVQN7jyK5QbrnHZ2rwmRVhnGAnT3bYEEG1xudtSsT03AcZtTG/BwmuXvPOJLck@NaQvIx/hfTgZ1lSw@M7ooqJlB74XLbC4W8QM0PMlMyQ5AVNEtwHpGRcSvM9tlt6ua2K4n5/JM6EhqZONbcVPU3Av0y9p4UaOKckGvZpU2OnNkeiboOINmpLrHlDdHfyNMxE6m4MPxNuaGxt0iOBUVARd7CNAtfC88cXT/Oum6RBrUmONKA4GRS2tWU0Ncgjl/@uu0VpQ2uLecl/pM5cs1mXVFfu276gdSVelAPsYe9@7VCPusR5kh1eVnIOhHQ@d36Nr187VhmCm@ezMCjrpkLnhn1tStds6rcONa8a4BPPX4cOzs9wdW7pgnyvwjioFAQJNRqOHNKJq4wroRV/rMRy6FLpXRCCEgAAz0j@H5c5vj5zqfU2qJN7gJmiuAtiHUQdYljtcrg8W51eK8H06GzUYZl8Q093cyr/9ywA4Pobavc7@NYVSI@SCmB4k@wOZJ2Nr/hMhOmtNOQ0MTlMYBynmP/Y81MiSdL9CZ/ueeLmh0s6XD8QAmwuX3LzipqrV64Pn1lOnUI4z5s0JdgeHoe9I5B@DqKtZqYuSjp0w8eX9tT@H5Dxv8FFxniB9i5IupIYLwUXWyQ8jZN9fOzDooBhC77PwSIiz/Q06h2ga748v5i3o2BaGj0HTLzqWrfc13GRHwKcE6WOtmYAW/NlOepvUAzHItXrgNcarxncGmAPY32s2iP8n3V0w9GnZU@oOcE5O1rSrM9WS8itafvN/RabHQ/eN8fqvFmezU6Inf3UEYvQ3@eczZY3FGGOeJerQ@RhfoH6vohhpbN50hcwhGwMRr2TMQAgLMkwlQHgU5WGvLh7/giroiI8DJhCPWjK7AEgm8TEraS1rh80yD@VeRHWuXKOdmPoLH7I2sMNAnTvRBHBsvXxbi7Wepvkx066wOW7q0cgPLLc8ssx55dhFzjS40mHy8WJGZddRvaWLE1OZiFHMsfL81NHbdL1oD4oHyB5@XjE/l3r1oi28jbZEKaqJIdAWcMFjPLoGsX3jiqhs4PWdVwVDxD7HtTnfanfV1VRqcFfE9jzVhDEt0eU/jTCXcQU2TRlWVQ1QjXIeuQ5pjTF1LrMk@eFRZPXH@hSAyk9pPdTvndMVRLtpsz1C/YoAtp0H9YytlcRX@90yEw3l6sJeR4K8tPA1Ne@9SwQp0BvK1CGOOQiNV2s/LIxMdO8tgoUJXV5VtLimuY4Nf/syvdXoIVvmjVchdWl6O0ncBvePTPXYZ08of1N159PMPQvvdU7NFENWzAFKfCTrNEGTHxx8Jj2Ykob3F7QHAJ7ESUCkof2OVDizLjfOCkLk@2QacEa7HW8l2KTWpxJ5Fo1PHElYLLvW3rhrx2tPMdzLQvbUL1ZCIf8dtl4jnZOj2yPmw1LyFBtlQnXhcpwm1Kdb@vYk5spXytDIgx9Yh4f7qyTayFHM116dMPN@cra47F33z4H3XNzc4KjvQH3WUjbjxvK/GgVSD5Vud0DXFrXw5LdhQzdJHaBcF@tVIIn/wYcNF8RmZjnnd7AxFE7A3jClGokMgX4KwzD6DU7upRPhoqKP1T0wUQU40ZSq4eiujPqx9mEHQSY@bCMt1aIm8pOrtsjwduyUJ0FExxsLQ1sGAkxN9sVKybw8dYGHbQrqOceDyDM9kanmxZemALPPi8QJUH6n9NKE64P4bpGI@t@OIKT4@AyH9kTQ0zoUyy/Fe4bLHCNryZTdXGByOEdANtuV8fqpK0vACn2PVQuvs0gh5I4iKXJMXG0l7FKRAiUO0jrqFqmST3GVU2mgnJdi7DgmnHAIkIHDpiClMQQ0gOjk3DU0esEGjlyw08WsMUQ2KUOv@atp1PICyLgpXqM5STC1BajjgjHXZCesE1opw8bh7MCJ0mxh2oG97CL1mgcfHmC4x0bd2DcwXCKT5NpW4vr7mNRthtifE2Bd6H22nxjm7SU5haqBbSeUZyFTh3bXhxs205qTbuwPUfMJccpJ6yBTWTxgouH4iLYBi36M4lyprRixZwXJNJBZVYi0qc2zYoUJ@m59jMZhNciDqYHlPM8G4BBLVBnygZ9zU0LSLiPK47jViLLP4EK055IJKyrICsLSpyF/JGPxuub1ZQzc@pRvgC9JysKg8mBF5Ath0xM8Ay7tA27ejyB04V5GioKaTW9QhTbNHlYQ9o2EnrPQ0GfmowhlOHUphc0egk9jCLhlOJIJ62n1C3kTGumQl@yhAt1xa9nM0ZRZrlJLq5W10yEyjAj@wlMBdEr4lk9z4AFPhRRQzAo0I5Z5lQVZb14fLIIL@dFVmkBfMCuwhnzyRx2hKQjug7VBdxnVKAsjye@J45X6TINQg2ZebXMvyyrOeggCOGQ3Vz6vj@7WrVBg/JBGzdox/HjBOcMCB7tWcFwCxqhwb5xiCUU28Pghj02zOk6OZVRDkkaQxhuNDpsi8N8Cey/plEMoHSy@m9p1HNxgqVcHOAd0xpW2KY@spI14SmZYc1@g761Rs9qJ54cZIMD4Xtj38tqKHIY60k5SbWL4a8U7LfOAHjXzmcLo8RdZ0a0E39QIY1xp2bt8mayMRcdcWwb9pbcFJCVpsXWZhLgpH6k182Wv1DAaJPWdBki4VOZrQX/aRtYaQo594I9U7Lh1J0drk/OTY4/f7UFHVvko3IxtiE/pUlvbStvU2m5zEbdsuS24kYIjLQ7ustyIQk7UrSmoiC333N7@VLaV9xeSXviZoxVMWq4kuVxaQubmJ9HtSJPinLUsqKxjDq1HPq9k0ZaFm@LifZuTdU8z35n4M49G5QLAgMx2K1onMlvrjJQsQ1b/lRAPS0WkwmkGDQQg2epNAm39G2Ie7bo06mGUWWRW14X1vqwdUuN9JsFc0FuwKbhQootidhq3UA8hKqQ1KFCo2c/3FCn3tuW5WJtjNo/5Dd9s8GeXbhYohZD8VcKW0Wjohq29JWLFslPcVoDgys3AvgdVz/86NDId2BsPG@ofv7wztYhPDiPEWVk136QRdecaPIIhuuDEGT8J2L@rWmZ7d01Iwq8CeGwESmZVZAGMafoCPsLRB6jqyNhD5A9FQ8ig3/4yNkTYOoIQGqB39lDcCUfvzd@wrHxxJPYMxgwlY@FmCiog9EUwmXc5Hd8y0QqQD4acSjhrg@EFORd9HKiLkcWO3NQbe9vXqy@fv3KxTcPa21K@mUDSx/8XacpgNS/iyqNzgbeECm@Vuv/AA)

```
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  4
              Source :  0
             Comment :  4
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  4
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1
```

Comment: Instead of `puts`, you could use [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p). The space can be omitted as well. To make it equivalent to `puts`, use `p"Hello, World!\n"` But I don't see the newline being required.

Comment: p adds quotes to the output, so it can't be used. however, you can use `$><<"Hello, World!"` for -1.

Answer (score 8):

## [CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html), 38 bytes

```css
/**/:after{content:"Hello, World!"/**/
```

CSS, despite not being an actual programming language, allows us to do basic output. This code creates a pseudo-element after every element on the page

Sloc's block comment detection is broken (as seen in other answers) and this is reported as 0 lines of source code. [See the sloc output here](https://tio.run/##tVltj9u4Ef6uX8G1e7CdteXdHA7IJXG217tre@ilAZoA/bD2HWSJtrSrtxPpXRub/PZ03ihTshO0H7oLiDQ1MxwOh88MR3G12Wht4iar7fPPw@Ew@JBmRtVNtW2iQkE3yYxtsvXO6kTtykQ3yqZaWd0URlUb@vH2lw8qz2JdGh0GP1b1ocm2qVXPr66fqxk2L9Q4nqi3UXO/M@ofVZqnkdHqdRFl@Z8LGp3dy2iY6DcB6hHc64NRC3UbKDWylY3ykaK/oarTg8niKIdJS01axFWikc5UuybWI6FrX/MwEsRVUejSjnyCx8ymSl4YkpKV27wnhYj4xQxHOgzrvIrvW/U8BnrRIS2yvU56pDSmdrVMQsqqqExO5/i5qO1hBIwaO/5MUXcu5NBMLFN5HGzRpBpBZxUEZVWSXKRbqPntb0uzmge6TN5tfsWV0uif5kVQ6sdfaUYeWpbzbUBiZRTGgPcZkG4DlO@IcTx89uHdT@9Cfhlstf2RFf15XzfamKwqcbPHeVRuJ2r2JghQZ7a36ttbhhcBKmJg@XGqkDEIeLGPqS7VICbXHkzVAFwzGcg7BXoPYYlPqzlMAB6X2mirysqqTZXn1SNsxPqgqlqXMImKd01@UOsmIu/xZDcotz7gMzf4LKo4zbBTZntsiKBZ4/MuJ2J6HqKC2pTfgwRfr3lnkjsSfGdIXsG/Ynrws66p4fE9UaVESg98Llvh8DdImSFlSmbIyoomiR4iUjKtpfkO2y293DZV9XA4EWdiQ1PnmtuGnibiX8YeaKEGzimJhn3aWOxYcyLqLkpoo7bEWu6I7l6ehplI3Y3hZ8YNja1NfiIwiRrijrZJ5Ft4/vT807zrJnlkNcmRBhQng8K2tozGgjxy@W@6W5TvaG0pL/mP3JtrNuuS6sZ/2xe0bsSLSoA97D2sPepRl7jMiuPLRs6BkM7n3q/xzUvPKkNw83IWR7XdNejcsK@72jeb@q1DzasG@MTz16GD8zNcPXN0UXlQcRo1CoKEGg1HHunEV8aX0Io/VWI59Kn0PopBCQCAr0j@H5c5vrnwqfU2stkDwExV3UepjpIOMax2OVxerM6vlWB6dDHqsEy@oKe/OU34exEBcP0NtfsdfOsapCdZAzC8yfZHss7GN3wm4vxOGnKalBwmMp5TzF/1/JRIsvxwxqd7nrj5/ooO1/eEAJurb7l5Qc31C9@HLxynziGcl7s8J9genoa9E5D@GkQ7zYytajp0w6dv3an9PyDjf4OLjPEC7V2Q9CUxXgoutkh4Hif7@NiHRQHDFny/BouIPNPzqHeErvny2eW8HQXT0ugzwMTrrnXrg02r8hjgvCh1sjUD2JqPy1F/g1I4FrleR7zWdM3gtgP2ONWnqj3B/0VHNxz9tOwJNWc4ZydLmvXZrIRcS9tvHrbY7HnwYXeqzuvlxeyM2NmbjliE/j7nbLa8pQhzwrtcHSMP8wvU90UMG13Ms76AIWRjMBqcjQEAYVmBqQwAn2o05MXd80dYlVTxccBU6lFTZg8AuctM2kpaa/uoQf65zIuwzpdzshtDb/FD1h5uEKB7J4oIlq1Pd3Ox1tusPHXSBS7fXz0C4Ynllh9POT8Ou8CRn046XC7OzLjsMrK3FHl2Ngs5kTlePjt31CZdD@qD8hGSl08n7N@0bo1oK2@zDWGqykoIlBYuYJRHWxTfO6qEzh5a27SpHiH2PaoPh1r/3DRVowZ/zWDPW0EQ355Q@qcR7iKmyGZX11VjEapB1hPPMaUpps5lPgVBXO1K@5YuNZDSQ3o/5XvHVGXJfspcv2CPIqBL92EtY3cVCfVex8x0e7WakOehoDCPjL0JnWeBOAV6O4EyxCEXqeliFdY7kzLNS6dAVVOXZyUtbmiOc/PPrsNwBVqEZreGq7C6Er3DDG7D@6/MdVwnT@h@0/XnPQz9S2/1Hk1kYQumIAV@kjXagIkvjh7TXkxpg9sLmkfgLqJEQPLQPkdKnBn3GydlYbIdMi1Yg72O91JsYsWZRK5TIxBXAib3vqUXfutpFXie61jYhur1Qjjkt8/Gc7RzBmR73GxYQoFqq0K4LlWB25TrcmvTQG6mfK2MiTAOiXl8vLNOboQczXQV0A235Ctrj8fdffscdM8tzRmO9gbcZyFt320o86NVIPlUlW4PcGldD8v2lzJ0m7kFwn21URme/Ftw0HJFZGKen/QGJk7aGcATplQjkSnAX2EYRm/Y0aV8MlRU/KGiDyaiGDcyqx6r5t6oV7MJOwgw82EZb50QP5Wd3LRHgrdloToLJjjYOhrYMBJibrcrVkzg40cXdNCuoJ5/PICwOBidb1p4YQo8@7xAlATpf0krzbg@hOsajZz74QhOjoPLcuRODDGhT7H8VnhosMA1vp5M1eUlIkdwBGy3XR2rk7ahAKTY91i5@DKDHEriIJZdiYmju4w1IkKg3ENaT9U6z@wYVzWZCsp1LcKCLeOAQ4QOHDAFKYkhpAdGZ@Goo9cZNPLkxu8dYIshsEsdfs1bT6eQF0TAS/UYx0mEuStGnRCOuyA9YZvQTh83DmcFTpLiDtUM7mGXrdE4@PIEpzs27sC4h@EUnybTthbX3ceqbjfEhJoC70IdtPnCNmkpzS1UC2g9o3gLnXq2vTzatp3UmXbhep6YK45TXlgDm8jiBRePxUWwDVr0BxLlTenEijkvSaSHyqxEos9tmhMpTtJz7a9kEEGLOJgeUM7z1QAMaoE6UzboS25aQMJ9XHEcdxJZ/hlUmPZEIqFtoqKuKHEW8ic@Gi9vV1POzKlH@QL0PjlRGEyOvIBsJWRigmfYpW3Y2/EEThfmaagopNX0ClFssytjC2nbSOiDAAW93xUMoQynLr2g0SvoYRSJpxRHOmk9pW4xZ1ozFYeSJVyqa349mzGKMsttdnm9umEiVIYZ2U9gKoheCc8aBAYs8LZKdgSDAu2YZU5VVdvF0yeH8HJeZJUOwAfsKpwxn81hR0g6ouuQreA@oyLleALxPXG8Rtd5FGvIzJtl@XHZzEEHQQiP7PYqDMPZ9aoNGpQPurhBO44fJzhnQPBozwqGW9AIDfaFQyyh2B0GP@yxYc7XyamMckzSGMJwo9FhWxzmS2D/NY1iAKWT1X9Lo4GPEyzl8gjvmNawwi71kZWsCU/JDGv2G/StNXpWO/HkKBscCN8b915WQ5HDOE8qSapbDH@lYL/1BsC79iFbGCXuOzOinfiDCmmMOzVrlzeTjbnsiGPbsLeUpoKsNK@2LpMAJw0Tvd5t@QsFjO5yS5chEj6V2Vrwn7aBlaaQcy/YMyUbTv3Z4frk3eT481db0HFFPioXYxvzU5r8zrXyNpeWy2zUrWtuG26EwEi7p7ssF5KwI0VrKgpy@x23V99K@4Lba2nP3IyxKkYNV7ICLm1hk/LzpFYUSFGOWlY0lVGvlkO/99JIy@JdMdHdramaF7jvDNx5YINyQWAgBrsTjQv5zVUGKrZhy58KqKfFYjKBFIMGYvAilybjlr4Ncc8VfTrVMKoscsvrwloftn6pkX6zYC7IDdg0XEhxJRFXrRuIh1AVkjpUaAzchxvq2INrWS7Wxqj9Q37TNxvsuYWLJawYir9SuCoaFdWwpa9ctEh@itMaGFz5ESDsuPrxR4dGvgNjEwRD9cPbn1wdIoDzmFBGdhNGRXLDiSaPYLg@CkHGfyLm35mW2d1dC6LAmxAOG5FSOAVpEHOKjrC/QOQxujkR9gjZU/UoMvhHiJw9AcYmAFIL/M4egyuF@L3xPY6NJ4HEnsGAqUIsxCSRjUZTCJfprrznWyZSAfLRiEcJd30gpCDvo5cXdTmyuJmjZvtw@3z1@fPn0Wg0GAzg@aqGcGnHg7/rPAdw@nfV5MnFYPKK38Lzc334Dw).

The below snippet has been modified (40 bytes) so that the snippet runner and some browsers that style the <html> (causing a double-output) display properly.

```css
/**/* :after{content:"Hello, World!"/**/
```

Answer (score 7):

## Nim, 24 bytes

```
 #[]#echo"Hello, World!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run//##y8vM/f9fQTk6Vjk1OSNfySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVHp/38A)

[Verify sloc](https://tio.run/##tVltb9vIEf7OX7GWepBkS5Sd4IBcLjr3mqTtoZcGaAL0g6U7UORKpM2345K2BMe/PZ23pZaUYrQfagPc1XJmdnZ29pnZYVhsNlqbsErK@sXX4XDofY4To8qq2FZBpqAbJaauknVT60g1eaQrVcda1brKjCo29OPDL59VmoQ6N9r33hblvkq2ca1eXF69UDNsXqlxOFEfguquMeofRZzGgdHqTRYk6Z8zGp3dyagf6Z881MO703ujFurGU2pUF3WQjhT9DVUZ700SBilMmmvSIiwijXSmaKpQj4Sufc3DSBAWWabzeuQSPCR1rOSFISlJvk17UoiIX8xwpMOwTovwrlXPYaAXHdIs2emoR0pjqillElJWBXl0PMf7rKz3I2DU2HFnCrpzIYdmYpnK4WCLRsUIOivPy4uc5CLdQs1vflua1dzTefRx8yuulEb/NM@8XD/8SjPy0DKfbz0SK6MwBrznQLr1UL4lxnH//PPHdx99fultdf2WFX2/KyttTFLkuNnjNMi3EzX7yfNQZ7a36ttbhhceKmJg@WGskNHzeLEPsc7VICTXHkzVAFwzGsg7BXoPYYmPqzlMAB4X18FW5UWtNkWaFg@wEeu9KkqdwyQqbKp0r9ZVQN7jyK5QbrnHZ2rwmRVhnGAnT3bYEEG1xudtSsT03AcZtTG/BwmuXvPOJLck@NaQvIx/hfTgZ1lSw@M7ooqJlB74XLbC4W8QM0PMlMyQ5AVNEtwHpGRcSvM9tlt6ua2K4n5/JM6EhqZONbcVPU3Av0y9p4UaOKckGvZpU2OnNkeiboOINmpLrHlDdHfyNMxE6m4MPxNuaGxt0iOBUVARd7CNAtfC88cXT/Oum6RBrUmONKA4GRS2tWU0Ncgjl/@uu0VpQ2uLecl/pM5cs1mXVFfu276gdSVelAPsYe9@7VCPusR5kh1eVnIOhHQ@d36Nr187VhmCm@ezMCjrpkLnhn1tStds6rcONa8a4BPPX4cOzs9wdW7pgnyvwjioFAQJNRqOHNKJq4wroRV/rMRy6FLpXRCCEgAAz0j@H5c5vj5zqfU2qJN7gJmiuAtiHUQdYljtcrg8W51eK8H06GzUYZl8Q093cyr/9ywA4Pobavc7@NYVSI@SCmB4k@wOZJ2Nr/hMhOmtNOQ0MTlMYBynmP/Y81MiSdL9CZ/ueeLmh0s6XD8QAmwuX3LzipqrV64Pn1lOnUI4z5s0JdgeHoe9I5B@DqKtZqYuSjp0w8eX9tT@H5Dxv8FFxniB9i5IupIYLwUXWyQ8jZN9fOzDooBhC77PwSIiz/Q06h2ga748v5i3o2BaGj0HTLzqWrfc13GRHwKcE6WOtmYAW/NlOepvUAzHItXrgNcarxncGmAPY32s2iP8n3V0w9GnZU@oOcE5O1rSrM9WS8itafvN/RabHQ/eN8fqvFmezU6Inf3UEYvQ3@eczZY3FGGOeJerQ@RhfoH6vohhpbN50hcwhGwMRr2TMQAgLMkwlQHgU5WGvLh7/giroiI8DJhCPWjK7AEgm8TEraS1rh80yD@VeRHWuXKOdmPoLH7I2sMNAnTvRBHBsvXxbi7Wepvkx066wOW7q0cgPLLc8ssx55dhFzjS40mHy8WJGZddRvaWLE1OZiFHMsfL81NHbdL1oD4oHyB5@XjE/l3r1oi28jbZEKaqJIdAWcMFjPLoGsX3jiqhs4PWdVwVDxD7HtTnfanfV1VRqcFfE9jzVhDEt0eU/jTCXcQU2TRlWVQ1QjXIeuQ5pjTF1LrMk@eFRZPXH@hSAyk9pPdTvndMVRLtpsz1C/YoAtp0H9YytlcRX@90yEw3l6sJeR4K8tPA1Ne@9SwQp0BvK1CGOOQiNV2s/LIxMdO8tgoUJXV5VtLimuY4Nf/syvdXoIVvmjVchdWl6O0ncBvePTPXYZ08of1N159PMPQvvdU7NFENWzAFKfCTrNEGTHxx8Jj2Ykob3F7QHAJ7ESUCkof2OVDizLjfOCkLk@2QacEa7HW8l2KTWpxJ5Fo1PHElYLLvW3rhrx2tPMdzLQvbUL1ZCIf8dtl4jnZOj2yPmw1LyFBtlQnXhcpwm1Kdb@vYk5spXytDIgx9Yh4f7qyTayFHM116dMPN@cra47F33z4H3XNzc4KjvQH3WUjbjxvK/GgVSD5Vud0DXFrXw5LdhQzdJHaBcF@tVIIn/wYcNF8RmZjnnd7AxFE7A3jClGokMgX4KwzD6DU7upRPhoqKP1T0wUQU40ZSq4eiujPqx9mEHQSY@bCMt1aIm8pOrtsjwduyUJ0FExxsLQ1sGAkxN9sVKybw8dYGHbQrqOceDyDM9kanmxZemALPPi8QJUH6n9NKE64P4bpGI@t@OIKT4@AyH9kTQ0zoUyy/Fe4bLHCNryZTdXGByOEdANtuV8fqpK0vACn2PVQuvs0gh5I4iKXJMXG0l7FKRAiUO0jrqFqmST3GVU2mgnJdi7DgmnHAIkIHDpiClMQQ0gOjk3DU0esEGjlyw08WsMUQ2KUOv@atp1PICyLgpXqM5STC1BajjgjHXZCesE1opw8bh7MCJ0mxh2oG97CL1mgcfHmC4x0bd2DcwXCKT5NpW4vr7mNRthtifE2Bd6H22nxjm7SU5haqBbSeUZyFTh3bXhxs205qTbuwPUfMJccpJ6yBTWTxgouH4iLYBi36M4lyprRixZwXJNJBZVYi0qc2zYoUJ@m59jMZhNciDqYHlPM8G4BBLVBnygZ9zU0LSLiPK47jViLLP4EK055IJKyrICsLSpyF/JGPxuub1ZQzc@pRvgC9JysKg8mBF5Ath0xM8Ay7tA27ejyB04V5GioKaTW9QhTbNHlYQ9o2EnrPQ0GfmowhlOHUphc0egk9jCLhlOJIJ62n1C3kTGumQl@yhAt1xa9nM0ZRZrlJLq5W10yEyjAj@wlMBdEr4lk9z4AFPhRRQzAo0I5Z5lQVZb14fLIIL@dFVmkBfMCuwhnzyRx2hKQjug7VBdxnVKAsjye@J45X6TINQg2ZebXMvyyrOeggCOGQ3Vz6vj@7WrVBg/JBGzdox/HjBOcMCB7tWcFwCxqhwb5xiCUU28Pghj02zOk6OZVRDkkaQxhuNDpsi8N8Cey/plEMoHSy@m9p1HNxgqVcHOAd0xpW2KY@spI14SmZYc1@g761Rs9qJ54cZIMD4Xtj38tqKHIY60k5SbWL4a8U7LfOAHjXzmcLo8RdZ0a0E39QIY1xp2bt8mayMRcdcWwb9pbcFJCVpsXWZhLgpH6k182Wv1DAaJPWdBki4VOZrQX/aRtYaQo594I9U7Lh1J0drk/OTY4/f7UFHVvko3IxtiE/pUlvbStvU2m5zEbdsuS24kYIjLQ7ustyIQk7UrSmoiC333N7@VLaV9xeSXviZoxVMWq4kuVxaQubmJ9HtSJPinLUsqKxjDq1HPq9k0ZaFm@LifZuTdU8z35n4M49G5QLAgMx2K1onMlvrjJQsQ1b/lRAPS0WkwmkGDQQg2epNAm39G2Ie7bo06mGUWWRW14X1vqwdUuN9JsFc0FuwKbhQootidhq3UA8hKqQ1KFCo2c/3FCn3tuW5WJtjNo/5Dd9s8GeXbhYohZD8VcKW0Wjohq29JWLFslPcVoDgys3AvgdVz/86NDId2BsPG@ofv7wztYhPDiPEWVk136QRdecaPIIhuuDEGT8J2L@rWmZ7d01Iwq8CeGwESmZVZAGMafoCPsLRB6jqyNhD5A9FQ8ig3/4yNkTYOoIQGqB39lDcCUfvzd@wrHxxJPYMxgwlY@FmCiog9EUwmXc5Hd8y0QqQD4acSjhrg@EFORd9HKiLkcWO3NQbe9vXqy@fv2qhjeroQ7jYvB3naaASv8uqjQ6G3wFp/wP)

sloc looks for `#` characters in Nim, but the regex is a little weird, as it cares about the position of the `#`. Presumably, this was done to try to work around the fact that it treats `##` comments separate from `#` comments. Specifically, sloc doesn't seem to know that Nim has block comments in the form of `#[` `]#`, so it treats `##` comments as block comments for its counting. This means that although we can take advantage of its misunderstanding of block comments fairly easily, we need a space at the start or it won't detect it. Or more accurately, it actually seems to detect it properly, somehow, despite there not seeming to be any code for block comments in the source. I'm really not quite sure why it works, I'd have to try to understand a regex for that.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
#!/usr/bin/rscript -e cat('Hello','World!')
```

Count the zero [source lines of code](https://tio.run/##tVptj9vGEf7OX7EnNZDko6g7GwEcx8o1ddI2aFwDtYF@OCkBRa5E3vEtXPJOwtm/3Z23pZaUbLQfega4q@XM7Ozs7DOzQ0fldqu1ieq0ap5/Ho/H3ockNaqqy10d5gq6cWqaOt20jY5VW8S6Vk2iVaPr3KhySz/e/vJBZWmkC6MD701ZHep0lzTq@dX1czXH5qWaRjP1NqzvW6P@USZZEhqtXudhmv05p9H5vYwGsf7BQz28e30waqluPaUmTdmE2UTR31hVycGkUZjBpIUmLaIy1khnyraO9EToutc8jARRmee6aCYuwWPaJEpeGJKSFrtsIIWI@MUcR3oMm6yM7jv1HAZ60SPN072OB6Q0ptpKJiFlVVjEp3P8nFfNYQKMGjvuTGF/LuTQTCxTORxs0bicQGfteUVZkFykW6rF7W8rs154uojfbX/FldLonxa5V@jHX2lGHloVi51HYmUUxoD3GZDuPJRviXE8ePbh3U/vAn7p7XTzhhX9eV/V2pi0LHCzp1lY7GZq/oPnoc5sbzW0twwvPVTEwPKjRCGj5/FiHxNdqFFErj3y1QhcMx7JOwV6j2GJT@sFTAAelzThThVlo7ZllpWPsBGbgyorXcAkKmrr7KA2dUje48iuUW51wGdm8JmXUZJip0j32BBBvcHnXUbE9DyEObUJvwcJrl6L3iR3JPjOkLycf0X04GdVUcPje6JKiJQe@Fx1wuFvlDBDwpTMkBYlTRI@hKRkUknzLbY7ermry/LhcCLORIamzjS3NT1NyL9Mc6CFGjinJBr2adtgpzEnou7CmDZqR6xFS3T38jTMROpuDT9TbmhsY7ITgXFYE3e4i0PXwoun558WfTfJwkaTHGlAcTIobGvHaBqQRy7/TX@LspbWlvCS/8icuebzPqmu3bdDQZtavKgA2MPew8ahnvSJizQ/vqzlHAjpYuH8mt68cqwyBjcv5lFYNW2Nzg372lau2dRvPWpeNcAnnr8eHZyf8fqZpQuLg4qSsFYQJNRkPHFIZ64yroRO/KkSq7FLpfdhBEoAAHxF8v@4zOnNhUutd2GTPgDMlOV9mOgw7hHDalfj1cX6/FoJpicXkx7L7At6uptTB7/nIQDX31C738G3rkF6nNYAw9t0fyTrbXzNZyLK7qQhp0nIYULjOMXi@4GfEkmaHc749MATt99d0eH6jhBge/WCm5fUXL90ffjCcuoMwnnRZhnB9vg07J2A9Ncg2mpmmrKiQzd@emFP7f8BGf8bXGSMF2jvg6QrifFScLFDwvM4OcTHISwKGHbg@zVYROTxz6PeEboWq2eXi24UTEujzwATr/vWrQ5NUhbHAOdEqZOtGcHWfFxNhhuUwLHI9CbktSYbBrcW2KNEn6r2BP8uerrh6KfVQKg5wzk/WdJ8yNZIyG1o@83DDps9Dz60p@q8Xl3Mz4id/9ATi9A/5JzPV7cUYU54V@tj5GF@gfqhiHGt80U6FDCGbAxGvbMxACAszTGVAeBTtYa8uH/@CKviMjoOmFI9asrsASDb1CSdpI1uHjXIP5d5Eda5ck52Y@wsfszaww0CdO9FEcGyzeluLjd6lxanTrrE5burRyA8sdzq4ynnx3EfOLLTScer5ZkZV31G9pY8S89mIScyp6tn547arO9BQ1A@QvLq6YT9m86tEW3lbbolTFVpAYGygQsY5dENih8cVUJnB62bpC4fIfY9qg@HSv9c12WtRn9NYc87QRDfnlD6pwnuIqbIpq2qsm4QqkHWE8/h0xS@dZlPnheVbdG8pUsNpPSQ3vt87/BVGu995voFexQBbboPa5naq0ig9zpiptur9Yw8DwUFWWiam8B6FohToLcVKEMccpGaLlZB1ZqEaV5ZBcqKujwraXFDc5ybf34dBGvQIjDtBq7C6kr0DlK4De@/MtdxnTyh/U3Xn/cw9C@903s0UQNb4IMU@EnW6AImvjh6THcxpQ3uLmgOgb2IEgHJQ/scKXFm3G@clIXJdsi0YA32Ot5LsUkjziRyrRqeuBIw2fcdvfA3jlae47mWhW2oXi@FQ367bDxHN6dHtsfNhiXkqLbKhetS5bhNmS52TeLJzZSvlRERRgExT4931tmNkKOZrjy64RZ8ZR3w2LvvkIPuuYU5w9HdgIcspO27LWV@tAok91Vh9wCX1vewdH8pQ7epXSDcV2uV4sm/BQct1kQm5vlJb2HiuJsBPMGnGolMAf4KwzB6w44u5ZOxouIPFX0wEcW4kTbqsazvjfp@PmMHAWY@LNOdFeKmsrOb7kjwtixVb8EEBztLAxtGQsztbs2KCXy8sUEH7QrquccDCPOD0dm2gxemwLPPC0RJkP4XtNKU60O4rsnEuh@O4OQ4uCom9sQQE/oUy@@EBwYLXNPrma8uLxE5vCNg2@3qWZ20DQQgxb7HysWXGeRQEgextAUmjvYyVosIgXIHaR1VqyxtpriqmS8o17cIC24YBywi9OCAKUhJDCEDMDoLRz29zqCRIzd6bwFbDIFd6vBr3no6hbwgAl6qx1hOIsxsMeqEcNoH6RnbhHb6uHE4K3CSFHuo5nAPu@yMxsGXJzjdsWkPxh0Mp/g087taXH8fy6rbEBNoCrxLddDmC9ukpTS3VB2gDYziLNR3bHt5tG03qTXt0vYcMVccp5ywBjaRxQsuHouLYBu06I8kypnSihVzXpJIB5VZiVif2zQrUpxk4NpfySC8DnEwPaCc56sBGNQCdXw26CtuOkDCfVxzHLcSWf4ZVPAHIpGwqcO8KilxFvInPhqvbtc@Z@bUo3wBep@sKAwmR15AtgIyMcEz7NI27JvpDE4X5mmoKKTV9ApRbNsWUQNp20ToPQ8FvW9zhlCGU5te0OgV9DCKRD7FkV5aT6lbxJnWXEWBZAmX6ppfz@eMosxym15er2@YCJVhRvYTmAqiV8yzep4BC7wt45ZgUKAds0xflVWzfPpkEV7Oi6zSAviIXYUz5rM57ARJJ3Qdakq4z6hQWR5PfE8cr9ZVFkYaMvN6VXxc1QvQQRDCIbu9CoJgfr3uggblgzZu0I7jxwnOGRA8urOC4RY0QoN94RBLKLaHwQ17bJjzdXIqoxyTNIYw3Gh02A6H@RI4fE2jGEDpZA3f0qjn4gRLuTzCO6Y1rLBNfWQlG8JTMsOG/QZ9a4Oe1U08O8oGB8L3xr6X1VDkMNaTCpJqF8NfKdhvnQHwrn3AFkaJ@96MaCf@oEIa407Nu@XNZWMue@LYNuwthSkhK83Knc0kwEmDWG/aHX@hgNE2a@gyRMJ9ma0Df78LrDSFnHvBHp9s6Luzw/XJucnx56@uoGOLfFQuxjbipzTZnW3lbSYtl9moW1Xc1twIgZF2T3dZLiRhR4rWVBTk9ltur15I@5Lba2nP3IyxKkYNV7I8Lm1hk/DzpFbkSVGOWlY0kVGnlkO/99JIy@JtMdHerama59nvDNx5YINyQWAkBrsTjXP5zVUGKrZhy58KqKfFYjKBFINGYvA8kybllr4Ncc8WfXrVMKoscsvrwloftm6pkX6zYC7Ijdg0XEixJRFbrRuJh1AVkjpUaPTshxvqNAfbslysjVH7h/ymbzbYswsXSzRiKP5KYatoVFTDlr5y0SL5KU5rYHDtRoCg5@rHHz0a@Q6MjeeN1Y9vf7J1CA/OY0wZ2U0Q5vENJ5o8guH6KAQZ/4mYf2c6Znt3zYkCb0I4bERKbhWkQcwpesL@ApHH6PpE2CNkT@WjyOAfAXIOBJgmBpBa4nf2CFwpwO@N73FsOvMk9oxGTBVgISYOm3DiQ7hM2uKeb5lIBchHIw4l3PWBkIK8i15O1OXIYmcO693D7fP158@fxxeL1tSLTVosav4PAWoO1CFcJf6us6yc@JN/l3UWX0xmn@v/AA)

I'm not sure whether this is completely valid.  It's a full program that must be launched directly from the shell (so it does not work in 'Try it Online' or 'rdrr.io' for instance, or when copy-pasted into the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) console).  Save as "helloworld.r" with execute permission, and run using `./helloworld.r` or, more verbosely, `exec helloworld.r > output.txt`.

[R](https://www.r-project.org/) does not support multi-line comments, so the 'pairing the comment delimiter' tricks available in other languages aren't possible.  The only (single line) comment character is `#`, and everything following it up to the next newline is not executed.  However, the shebang line starting with `#!` is counted by "sloc" as a comment, even though it will be read and interpreted by the program loader.

Usually, the shebang line simply tells the program loader which interpreter to use to run the rest of the program.  So, this is a more-conventional 2-line (sloc=1) [R](https://www.r-project.org/) program to accomplish the same task:

```r
#!/usr/bin/rscript
cat('Hello','World!')
```

But - we can also include command-line arguments in the shebang line, and the rscript interpreter accepts the `-e` flag to pass it the program code as an argument, which is what the sloc=0 code does here.

So: the program is valid in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) and the program code is run by [R](https://www.r-project.org/), but it requires to be launched from the shell and uses the help of the program loader.  Is this valid?  I don't know.  But it's the only way that I could think of to 'trick' sloc in a language without multi-line comments...

Comment: Why `exec helloworld.r`? That would replace your shell…

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I'll be honest: I don't really understand this stuff.  I just tried it out both ways and it worked for me...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this counts as R code. It uses a call to R, but you can't execute it by any of the standard ways of calling R code (i.e. with `source`, `Rscript`, `R CMD BATCH`...). The language here is something like "shell on a system with R installed", not R...

Comment: In a similar vein, if "shell" were a language permitted by the challenge or if we consider this general approach valid, we could do `#!/bin/sed s/.*/Hello, World!/` (31 bytes)

Comment: @Nye - (wouldn't the language then be shell+sed, and wouldn't that exact program require input?)  but anyway, I don't think that the fact that the 'shebang' approach could be used for more-than-one language (or shell+language combination) is the problem here.  The '/**/'  approach is obviously Ok for dozens of languages...  The question is whether the program is actually being executed by R or by shell+R.

Comment: @RobinRyder - Yes - this is exactly why I wasn't sure about the validity of the answer (and I did point-out that it can't be run by the more-standard ways)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - no, that program works as written without any arguments or input - try it out!

Comment: @Nye - Got it.  But other points still stand.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl5

```
$ cat script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -Esay(Hello.chr(44).chr(32).world.chr(33))
```

```
$ ./script.pl
Hello, world!
```

```
sloc script.pl

---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  1
       Block comment :  0
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

Comment: because it's code golf the number of bytes should appear currently 59, [another solution 39 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/nys5sUTBxkbd1c9FXcFOoTi5KLOgRK8gh0tZUb@0uEg/KTNPvyC1KEdB17U4sVK7UMMjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRkwuoj4srOSM3P0VBuwJJO5eePhKnPFlBN1kBSUjBTs2I6/9/AA "Bash – Try It Online")
or [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9DwT/8gtKMvPziv/ruhYnVmoXanik5uTk6yiE5xflpChqAgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") depending on counting

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is actually Perl, I think this is your shell interpreting the file as when tested in TIO it complains that `-E` can't be set via shebang: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19ZUb@0uEg/KTNPvwAooqDrWpxYqeGRmpOTr5ecUaRhYqIJpo2NNPXK84tyUiA8Y03N//8B "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings It must depend on your shell? > zero_line_hello_world.pl
Hello, world!

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl -Esay'Hello World!`  (35 bytes)

Comment: @quantum mechanic, the behavior of shebang wrt extra spaces is system dependent. Mind mentioning your OS?

Comment: @MingyeWang OS is Linux (Ubuntu). I'm not acquainted with all the ways this can go wrong, so feel free to point me to a resource.

Answer (score 5):

## Lua, 28 bytes

```lua
--[=[]=]print"Hello, World!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVltj9u4Ef6uX8G1e7CdteXdBAfkcvFtr0naHnppgCZAP9i@gyzRlnb1dqK0a2Ozvz2dN8qU7ATth@4CIk3NDIfD4TPDUVhst1qbsErK@vmX4XDofYoTo8qq2FVBpqAbJaaukk1T60g1eaQrVcda1brKjCq29OP9L59UmoQ6N9r33hTloUp2ca2eX10/VzNsXqpxOFHvg@quMeofRZzGgdHqdRYk6Z8zGp3dyagf6Z881MO70wejFmrpKTWqizpIR4r@hqqMDyYJgxQmzTVpERaRRjpTNFWoR0LXvuZhJAiLLNN5PXIJHpI6VvLCkJQk36U9KUTEL2Y40mHYpEV416rnMNCLDmmW7HXUI6Ux1ZQyCSmrgjw6neNdVtaHETBq7LgzBd25kEMzsUzlcLBFo2IEnbXn5UVOcpFuoebL31ZmPfd0Hn3Y/oorpdE/zTMv1w@/0ow8tMrnO4/EyiiMAe8zIN15KN8S47j/7NOHtx98funtdP2GFX23LyttTFLkuNnjNMh3EzX7yfNQZ7a36ttbhhceKmJg@WGskNHzeLEPsc7VICTXHkzVAFwzGsg7BXoPYYmP6zlMAB4X18FO5UWttkWaFg@wEZuDKkqdwyQqbKr0oDZVQN7jyK5QbnnAZ2rwmRVhnGAnT/bYEEG1wedtSsT0PAQZtTG/BwmuXvPOJLck@NaQvIx/hfTgZ1lSw@N7ooqJlB74XLXC4W8QM0PMlMyQ5AVNEtwHpGRcSvM9tjt6uauK4v5wIs6EhqZONbcVPU3Av0x9oIUaOKckGvZpW2OnNieiboOINmpHrHlDdHfyNMxE6m4NPxNuaGxj0hOBUVARd7CLAtfC88fnT/Oum6RBrUmONKA4GRS2tWU0Ncgjl/@uu0VpQ2uLecl/pM5cs1mXVFfu276gTSVelAPsYe9@41CPusR5kh1fVnIOhHQ@d36Nb145VhmCm@ezMCjrpkLnhn1tStds6rcONa8a4BPPX4cOzs9w/czSBflBhXFQKQgSajQcOaQTVxlXQiv@VInV0KXS@yAEJQAAviH5f1zm@ObCpda7oE7uAWaK4i6IdRB1iGG1q@HqYn1@rQTTo4tRh2XyFT3dzan837MAgOtvqN3v4FvXID1KKoDhbbI/knU2vuIzEaa30pDTxOQwgXGcYv5jz0@JJEkPZ3y654nbH67ocP1ACLC9esHNS2quX7o@fGE5dQrhPG/SlGB7eBr2TkD6WxBtNTN1UdKhGz6@sKf2/4CM/w0uMsYLtHdB0pXEeCm42CLheZzs42MfFgUMW/D9Fiwi8kzPo94RuuarZ5fzdhRMS6PPABOvu9YtD3Vc5McA50Spk60ZwNZ8Xo36GxTDsUj1JuC1xhsGtwbYw1ifqvYI/xcd3XD0adUTas5wzk6WNOuz1RJya9p@c7/DZs@D982pOq9XF7MzYmc/dcQi9Pc5Z7PVkiLMCe9qfYw8zC9Q3xcxrHQ2T/oChpCNwah3NgYAhCUZpjIAfKrSkBd3zx9hVVSExwFTqAdNmT0AZJOYuJW00fWDBvnnMi/COlfOyW4MncUPWXu4QYDunSgiWLY53c3FRu@S/NRJF7h8d/UIhCeWW30@5fw87AJHejrpcLU4M@Oqy8jekqXJ2SzkROZ49ezcUZt0PagPykdIXj2esH/XujWirbxNtoSpKskhUNZwAaM8ukbxvaNK6OygdR1XxQPEvgf16VDqd1VVVGrw1wT2vBUE8e0RpT@NcBcxRTZNWRZVjVANsh55jilNMbUu8@R5YdHk9Xu61EBKD@n9lO8dU5VE@ylz/YI9ioA23Ye1jO1VxNd7HTLT8mo9Ic9DQX4amPrGt54F4hTobQXKEIdcpKaLlV82JmaaV1aBoqQuz0pa3NAc5@afXfv@GrTwTbOBq7C6Er39BG7D@2/MdVwnT2h/0/XnIwz9S@/0Hk1UwxZMQQr8JGu0ARNfHD2mvZjSBrcXNIfAXkSJgOShfY6UODPuN07KwmQ7ZFqwBnsd76XYpBZnErlWDU9cCZjs@5Ze@GtHK8/xXMvCNlSvF8Ihv102nqOd0yPb42bDEjJUW2XCdaky3KZU57s69uRmytfKkAhDn5jHxzvr5EbI0UxXHt1wc76y9njs3bfPQffc3JzhaG/AfRbS9sOWMj9aBZJPVW73AJfW9bBkfylDy8QuEO6rlUrw5C/BQfM1kYl53uotTBy1M4AnTKlGIlOAv8IwjN6wo0v5ZKio@ENFH0xEMW4ktXooqjujfpxN2EGAmQ/LeGeFuKns5KY9ErwtC9VZMMHBztLAhpEQs9ytWTGBjzc26KBdQT33eABhdjA63bbwwhR49nmBKAnS/5xWmnB9CNc1Gln3wxGcHAdX@cieGGJCn2L5rXDfYIFrfD2ZqstLRA7vCNh2uzpWJ219AUix77Fy8XUGOZTEQSxNjomjvYxVIkKg3EFaR9UyTeoxrmoyFZTrWoQF14wDFhE6cMAUpCSGkB4YnYWjjl5n0MiRG360gC2GwC51@DVvPZ1CXhABL9VjLCcRprYYdUI47oL0hG1CO33cOJwVOEmKPVQzuIddtkbj4MsTnO7YuAPjDoZTfJpM21pcdx@Lst0Q42sKvAt10OYr26SlNLdQLaD1jOIsdOrY9vJo23ZSa9qF7TlirjhOOWENbCKLF1w8FhfBNmjRn0mUM6UVK@a8JJEOKrMSkT63aVakOEnPtb@RQXgt4mB6QDnPNwMwqAXqTNmgr7hpAQn3cc1x3Epk@WdQYdoTiYR1FWRlQYmzkD/y0Xi1XE85M6ce5QvQe7KiMJgceQHZcsjEBM@wS9uwr8cTOF2Yp6GikFbTK0SxbZOHNaRtI6H3PBT0sckYQhlObXpBo1fQwygSTimOdNJ6St1CzrRmKvQlS7hU1/x6NmMUZZZlcnm9vmEiVIYZ2U9gKoheEc/qeQYs8L6IGoJBgXbMMqeqKOvF45NFeDkvskoL4AN2Fc6Yz@awIyQd0XWoLuA@owJleTzxPXG8SpdpEGrIzKtV/nlVzUEHQQiHbHnl@/7set0GDcoHbdygHcePE5wzIHi0ZwXDLWiEBvvKIZZQbA@DG/bYMOfr5FRGOSZpDGG40eiwLQ7zJbD/mkYxgNLJ6r@lUc/FCZZyeYR3TGtYYZv6yEo2hKdkhg37DfrWBj2rnXhylA0OhO@NfS@rochhrCflJNUuhr9SsN86A@Bde58tjBL3nRnRTvxBhTTGnZq1y5vJxlx2xLFt2FtyU0BWmhY7m0mAk/qR3jQ7/kIBo01a02WIhE9lthb8p21gpSnk3Av2TMmGU3d2uD45Nzn@/NUWdGyRj8rF2Ib8lCa9ta28TaXlMht1y5LbihshMNLu6S7LhSTsSNGaioLcfs/t1QtpX3J7Le2ZmzFWxajhSpbHpS1sYn6e1Io8KcpRy4rGMurUcuj3XhppWbwtJtq7NVXzPPudgTv3bFAuCAzEYLeicSa/ucpAxTZs@VMB9bRYTCaQYtBADJ6l0iTc0rch7tmiT6caRpVFbnldWOvD1i010m8WzAW5AZuGCym2JGKrdQPxEKpCUocKjZ79cEOd@mBblou1MWr/kN/0zQZ7duFiiVoMxV8pbBWNimrY0lcuWiQ/xWkNDK7dCOB3XP34o0Mj34Gx8byh@vn9W1uH8OA8RpSR3fhBFt1woskjGK6PQpDxn4j5t6ZltnfXjCjwJoTDRqRkVkEaxJyiI@wvEHmMrk6EPUD2VDyIDP7hI2dPgKkjAKkFfmcPwZV8/N74EcfGE09iz2DAVD4WYqKgDkZTCJdxk9/xLROpAPloxKGEuz4QUpB30cuJuhxZ7MxBtbtfPl9/@fJlNlsuluvFuoRgWQ/@rtMUkOnfRZVGF4Mv4OD/AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 30 bytes

If using Python 2, [nobody's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215742/99505) can be improved slightly.

```
'''"""''';print"Hello, World!"
```

`sloc` outputs

```
{ total: 1,
  source: 0,
  comment: 1,
  single: 0,
  block: 1,
  mixed: 0,
  empty: 0,
  todo: 0,
  blockEmpty: 0 }
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/X11dXUlJCUhaFxRl5pUoeaTm5OTrKITnF@WkKCr9//8fAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Browser), 34 Bytes

```js
/**/console.log`Hello, World!`/**/
```

```sh
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  1
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

## Python, 36 Bytes

```python
'''#''';print("Hello, World!");"'''"
```

```sh
---------- Result ------------

            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  1
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1

----------------------------
```

Comment: Nice golfing!  You can get it [even shorter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Xx0MrAuKMvNKNJQ8UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUlTStlYBySv//AwA) by leaving out the ```#```...

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net), with various commandline shenanigans, 0-33

Depending how I read [Command-line flags on front ends](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), various of these answers may apply.

I feel none do, so downvotes are fine and expected on this one :) I'm posting it more as an exploration of the problem-space, perhaps towards an eventual argument that a solution is not possible in PHP, than an answer that I expect to be accepted.

I've given my arguments against them all, summarized with **opinionated bold statements**, because that naturally makes the arguments more true. I'm very interested to hear counterarguments, or additional arguments, in the comments!

### php -r 'echo"Hello, World!";', 0

One interpretation is that nothing on the commandline counts, but that the entire commandline is treated as a kind of "language dialect name" for the entry.

Against: **All code should be counted**. Otherwise, this approach makes any contest where bytes matter trivial in almost any language, by offloading all work to the CLI. The parameters to the -r flag here are not a "flag to choose a language option", they are "code", and should be counted as such.

### PHP -r, 20

```
php -r 'echo"Hello, World!";'
```

It could be argued that, while we count the code on the CLI, the sloc requirement only applies to the contents of source files. If there is no source file, then there are no code lines in source files!

Against: **All counted code should be passed to sloc**. Every language lets you slap code in the cli params. The challenge isn't meant to degrade into "run hello world without using a source file", so this isn't an interesting solution to the challenge.

### PHP -r ignoring quotes, 29

```
php -r '/**/echo "Hello, World!";/**/'
```

So we can pass in a minimal code sample on the commandline, getting all the benefits of avoiding PHP's <? requirement, without paying any significant penalty.

Against: **Necessary escaping of code should count as code**. There's no good argument FOR ignoring the quotes. Not-ignoring them makes challenges more interesting anyway.

So I'd argue that all characters which are counted should be passed to sloc, and this solution is wrapped in quotes, and the quotes should be counted. A quoted string counts as a code line in sloc. So, this fails the sloc test.

### PHP -r plus shell escapes, 33

```
php -r/**/echo\"Hello,\ World\!\"\;/**/
```

Against: **This is no longer PHP.** We're not, now, really coding in PHP, we're coding in (some shell) + PHP. If this were submitted as a bash script it'd count as 39 characters, and it'd fail the sloc test. We shouldn't get to reduce the count and pretend it passes, just by pretending it's run in one of the utilities the shell called.

### PHP with filepath and param ordering, 16.

This one's a two-parter! First, a file called `/x`, containing only our 13 character output string:

```
Hello, World!
```

Call it as:

```
php //x
```

Then, assuming 1) we count the filename as it is used on the commandline, and 2) we prepend that to the code we pass to sloc, because everything counted is code, sloc interprets it as a one-line comment.

Against: **both assumptions above are dumb.**

### PHP with various failed efforts, inf

Including these just as informational: trying both -r and a file specifier, to address the "depends how we concatenate" problem, above.

1. filename for comment, then -r for code.

   php //x -r 'echo "hi"';

The -r param did not run if a filename preceded it on the line. Same was true of the `-B`, `-R`, `-E`, `-F` params.

Against: **Given the -r flag doesn't count, it's hard to see how this woulda been counted. And it doesn't work anyway.**

2. Maybe the BREF group didn't work because they need actual input lines to parse, since they control per-input-line behavior?

   echo | php //x -B 'echo "hi"';

Same deal. They don't run if a filename for an empty file precedes them on the line. Same was true of the `-R`, `-E`, `-F` params.

Against: **This is now (some shell), and it doesn't work.**

3. The `-w` param is "Output source with stripped comments and whitespace." which almost sounds like an exact description of the challenge! Using `php -w x.php`, a source file like

   /**/Hello, World!/**/

... feels like it should work.

Against: **A coding challenge requires that the code runs.** No actual code was executed, and I feel that's required, to be in the spirit of a coding challenge. More importantly, it doesn't work: without a leading `<?`, PHP doesn't see this as PHP code, so does not strip the comments.

4. Trying variations on this approach, turns out `-w` does not work with `-r`.
5. But `-w` does run with direct or piped input. However, these have the exact same problem as using a file: PHP requires the leading `<?`.
6. What about exploiting ini file params?

   php -a -d cli.prompt='"Hello, World!"'

Against: **Doesn't run code, doesn't work.** Almost works, but also outputs "Interactive mode enabled\n\n".

### Exhaustive exploration of PHP-CLI args

Some push unwanted output to stdout that cannot be modified or redirected through config or code, so are unusable:

- `-a` Run interactively.
- `-h` Help.
- `-i` Show info.
- `--ini` list ini files.
- `-l` Lint.
- `-m` Module list.
- `--rf` function info.
- `--rc` class info.
- `--re` ext info.
- `--rz` Zend ext info.
- `--ri` ext config info.
- `-s` Prettyprint source.
- `-v` Version.

Some seem to offer no advantage over simpler alternatives:

- `-B` Begin code. No better than -r?
- `-E` Run at end. No better than -r?
- `-f` File. No better than default exec file param?
- `-F` File every line. No better than default exec file param?
- `-R` Run every line. No better than -r?

Some seem irrelevant, affecting neither perception as a comment, nor output:

- `-c` Config path. Irrelevant?
- `-e` Debug info. Irrelevant?
- `-H` Hide args from ps. Irrelevant?
- `-n` No Config. Irrelevant?
- `-S` Webserver. Irrelevant?
- `-t` Docroot. Irrelevant?

This leaves us with just four that look potentially exploitable.

- `-d` Define INI entry, which could include these likely candidates:

  - `auto_append_code`/`auto_prepend_code` could help somehow, but not sure how they'd be any better than the `-f` flag.
  - `cli.prompt` already tried above.
  - `memcache.*`/`opcache.*` could create output then modify code? Feels an invalid solution, though, even if it worked.
  - `filter.default` I think only filters input, not output and certainly not code.
  - `output_buffering` feels like a VERY likely candidate.
  - `output_handler` feels like a VERY likely candidate.
- `-r` Run code. Explored above, no success.
- `-w` Print stripped source. Explored above, no success.
- `-z` zend ext. Would require a zend extension that could help us.

Comment: Edited: not tested yet, but I think a solution *might* be possible with output buffering turned on :D

Answer (score 2):

976 9

JavaScript (Browser), 34 Bytes

```javascript
/**/console.log`Hello, World!`/**/
```

### Result

```
            Physical :  1
              Source :  0
             Comment :  1
 Single-line comment :  0
       Block comment :  1
               Mixed :  0
 Empty block comment :  0
               Empty :  0
               To Do :  0

Number of files read :  1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This appears to be a duplicate of an [existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215741/79857).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 30 bytes

```cs
/**/Write("Hello, World!")/**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P9fX0tLP7wosyRVQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSRMk8/8/AA)